# Is there an R function to collate row values and then convert into columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, format

I want to rearrange my dataset by aggregating similar species and site, while converting them into a format like this below.

```
>
Species Value  Site
A         1      D
A         2      D
B         3      E
B         4      E
C         1      F
C         2      F
```

into

```
>
Species D  E  F
A       3  1  0                 
B       0  7  0    
C       0  0  3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Sorry if the formatting is weird as this is my first time asking. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not sure if duplicate because OP is also summing..

Answer (score 1):

- Try this

```
xtabs(Value ~ Species + Site , data = df)
```

- Output

```
       Site
Species D E F
      A 3 0 0
      B 0 7 0
      C 0 0 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Species, Site) %>%  
  summarise(sum = sum(Value)) %>%  
  pivot_wider(names_from = Site, 
              values_from = sum, 
              values_fill = 0)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   Species [3]
  Species     D     E     F
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A           3     0     0
2 B           0     7     0
3 C           0     0     3
```

Comment: You can do `df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Site, values_from = Value, values_fn = sum, values_fill = 0)`, no need to `group_by` and `summarize`

Answer (score 0):

With `tapply()`:

```
tapply(df$Value, list(df$Species, df$Site), sum, default = 0)

#   D E F
# A 3 0 0
# B 0 7 0
# C 0 0 3
```